# Local backend is returned by browser when using proxy_pass

Tags: wordpress, nginx, lua

I am trying to configure `Wordpress` installed in local network and is reached through `proxy_pass` directive on another local server, but response comes in the browser as an address with local backend, please see following configuration:

```
+--------+ 
| router |
+--------+
  port forwarded :80 -> 1888 

+-------+
| nginx |
+-------+
  in lua block request is checked

  local site = string.lower(ngx.var.http_host)
  local backend = "http://192.168.0.20:1888"  # here runs WP
  
  # here only if request comes to 'some_site.com' backend
  # address is changed
  if site == "some_site.com" 
  then 
    backend = "http://another_local_address"
  end

  return backend
  ...
  
  proxy_pass $backend;
```

When I access a domain in the address bar I see:

[image: response]

Please help me to understand the right configuration so requests are passed correctly to my local server.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your post.  use one `=` to assign a variable.  use 2 `==` to test for equality.  `if site == 'some_site.com'`

For testing purposes, pick one:

```
local ngx  = { var = { http_host = nil } }

ngx .var .http_host  = 'http://some_site.com'
ngx .var .http_host  = 'https://some_site.com'
ngx .var .http_host  = 'http://some_site.com/this'
ngx .var .http_host  = 'https://some_site.com/that'
ngx .var .http_host  = 'http://192.168.0.20:1888'
ngx .var .http_host  = 'https://192.168.0.20:1888'
```

Don't overwrite `ngx .var .http_host` during production. Also, return value instead of print()

---

```
local site_name  = 'some_site.com'
local site  = string.lower( ngx .var .http_host )

--  lstrip( http:// or https:// )  AND  rstrip( anything after the name )
local stripped  = site :gsub( 'http[s]-://', '' ) :sub( 1, #site_name )
local backend  = 'http://192.168.0.20:1888'

if stripped == site_name then
    backend  = 'http://another_local_address'
end

print( backend )  --  used print() here, for testing purposes
--  return backend
```

Comment: Thanks, I posted question with  the typo, but the config is correct. It looks to me that just something goes wrong when response is returned and somehow local address is displayed in address bar.